# TIFF file issue

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, rasterization

[image]I started georeferencing an image.  A TIFF file is saved in my desktop. But I couldn't view the image of the map ( while seeing the icon on desktop). I then add the raster layer in QGIS. But the map has been compressed to a single thick line and has been rotated with black background. How to fix this? Attached the image here.

process:Initially I downloaded the map as jpeg from the site. Then went to raster and clicked georeference. A pop up window was opened. Clicked open raster and selected the image that I downloaded. And placed the points on four sides of the map and clicked settings and then clicked transformation setting. And set the CRS and output raster as shown in image attached here. And clicked ok after which I clicked start georeference. After that I opened my folder to check the georeferenced image where I couldnt find the map instead I found a black image with map that has been compressed and rotated as shown in my uploaded image
[image]

Comment: You should mention *how* you are doing the georeferencing, and more details about the original (ungeoreferenced) image.

Comment: this looks like your picture is heavily distorted. how many georeferencing points did you use? you should have at least(!) 3, the more the better. also, you points should be as close to the edge of the original picture as possible

Comment: looks like you've switch X & Y in either pts 3 & 4 or 1 & 2

Comment: in your screenshot you have no reference data loaded in qgis - what are you referencing your didugal.jpg to? After you added a point on your raster, what are you choosing in the pop-up windows? choose from map canvas?